# Warning when trying to convert timestamp to readable format foreach instance while looping thorugh an array

Tags: php, arrays, timestamp

Warning when trying to convert timestamp to readable format foreach instance while looping through an array.

```
<?php
    $json_feed = "http://localhost/sample/json/blog.json";
    $json = file_get_contents($json_feed);
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    $dateCreated = $array['post'].dateCreated;
    $date = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $dateCreated);

    foreach($obj['post'] as $article_array){
        $url = $article_array['url'];
        $title = $article_array['title'];
        $category = $article_array['category'];
        $large_summary = $article_array['wp_post_content'];
        $date = $article_array[$date];

        $post = array(
            'post_title' => $title,
            'post_content' => $large_summary,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'comment_status' => 'closed',
            'dateCreated' => $date,
            'post_template' => 'content.php'
        );

        wp_insert_post ($post, $wp_error);
    }
?>
```

> Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in /Users/andrew/Desktop/newtest.php on line 6

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `$array` and `dateCreated` in `$array['post'].dateCreated;`?

Comment: What is `dateCreated` that you appear to be concatenating to the end of  `$array['post']` in this line `$dateCreated = $array['post'].dateCreated;` ??? I would say that should be generating an error

Comment: ^ you guys talking to each other again? @u_mulder and Riggs.

Comment: You need to strtotime the variable $date = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime($dateCreated));

Answer (score 0):

You need to strtotime the variable

```
$date = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime($dateCreated))
```